# How to filter a list with a condition that depends on more than one element

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Given a list `L` I want to keep an element `L(i)` if it exists at least one value `j > i` such that `L(j)` is a multiple of `L(i)`, otherwise `L(i)` should be discarded.

It is quite simple to do that by means of imperative programming paradigms, but I would like to do that using functional programming.

Is that possible to use the `filter` method? If so, how to write the condition (i.e. the parameter of the `filter` function) ? Otherwise, what can I do?

Comment: This looks like a case for [`sliding`](http://daily-scala.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/iteratorsliding.html) across the `List`.

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
val l = (1 to 100)
l.tails.collect { case (head +: tail) if tail.exists(_ % head == 0) => head } .toList
```

`tail` produces an iterator that returns in each step the input minus one element, e.g.

```
(1 to 10).tails.foreach(println)
```

gives

```
Vector(1, 2, 3, 4)
Vector(2, 3, 4)
Vector(3, 4)
Vector(4)
Vector()
```

You can view these 'tails' as a head element to which you want to apply a filter and a tail in itself that is used to find out whether to keep the head.

The `collect` method is useful here, because it takes a partial function, so you only need to specify the cases where you actually retain a value—like `filter`—, while at the same time it acts like a `map` by letting you specify how the filtered value is to be collected.

So we can match on tails that have at least one head element and a tail of any size, and then see if in that tail there exists an element that is a multiple of the head. I use a *guard* here for the match case, so the match is a double filter. First, the tail must be non-empty, second there must be multiple. A multiple means that the modulus is zero. If the case matches, just return the verified head element.

Finally, since without specific type annotations the `collect` will just return another iterator, we turn the result into a list with `toList`.

Answer (score 2):

A more "explicit" one - you accumulate elements in a case if tail has a multiple of head:

```
(1 to 10).tails.foldLeft(List[Int]())((acc, tl) => tl match {
  case h +: t if (t.exists(_ % h == 0)) => h :: acc
  case _ => acc
}).reverse
```